# Include javascript file with PHP code in it

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I've done some javascript with PHP in it, like this:

```
var currentTotalContribution = <?php echo $myContribution; ?>;
```

I want to have that content in my javascript file instead, and then just import it. I don't even know if that is possible, and if it is, how do I do it?

Comment: set your php value in a variable and then use that variable in your js file

Comment: I don't think you can echo to a JavaScript file, but if your script was in-line within HTML (<script></script>) you'll be able to echo out the Php variable to it.

Comment: use var currentTotalContribution = <?php $myContribution; ?>; in your page.php, not in your .js. Declare currentTotalContribution before you .js load as a global variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**at the end of your example.php**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      var currentTotalContribution = <?= $myContribution; ?>;
 </script>
```

**in your jsExample.js**

use **currentTotalContribution** variable

```
function test(){
   return currentTotalContribution;
}
```